# GSON: how to parse nested objects?

Tags: android, json, gson

I have a JSON:

```
[{
   "id": 100500,
   "products": [...array of JSON Objects...],
   "areas": [...array of JSON Objects...],
   ...(30 more fields)
},
{...},
....]
```

And class Store:

```
public class Store {
      public  int id;
      public  List<Product> products;
      public  List<Area> areas;
      public ...(30 more fields)
}
```

ok, it works fine. But server can respond the next json:

```
[{
   "id": 100500,
   "products": [1, 2, 3, 4...], << int array
   "areas": [5, 6, 7, 8...],    << int array
   ...(30 more fields)
},
{...},
....]
```

As you can see, "products" – is array of IDs, but not an array of real objects "Product". How I can parse this json into class Store correctly (i.e. create list of Products with id from the array)?

Comment: I would argue the server is needlessly complicating things here, and shouldn't return different data types under the same key name.

Comment: I can't to correct the response. I can to use JSONObject and serialize the response manually, but I think that it is not good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to hack around this server-side design decision. Assuming that you have no other way of predicting what data-types the server will return:

What I would do is create `class StoreB` with `Integer` lists.

```
public class StoreB {
      public  int id;
      public  List<Integer> products;
      public  List<Integer> areas;
      public ...(30 more fields)
}
```

Now you can try to parse the JSON into your original `Store` class. Wrap it in GSON parse exception, so that when that fails, you catch it, and attempt to de-serialize into `StoreB`.

Comment: As I understand – I can't to set a custom serializer into gson for one of my fields manually. thanks.